# Update sqlite column type

Tags: android, sqlite

The columns in my table are currently "text", I need to change them to "text collate nocase". How would I go about doing this without losing data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run an `ALTER TABLE` command on the column. You should not lose data, **but test first**.

Check out [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) for the exact syntax;

Comment: The important thing to pick up from the docs, is that anything can be stored in any column. The type given to it is more of a hint of what type of data it there.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something similar. I used RazorSQL.

[RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/features/sqlite_features.html)